# Ignoring missing files in a specific folder with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

[image]

There're some unimportant files missing from my webapp dev environment which I want to ignore/skip loading since each request is taking up 25 seconds as I see in the networks tab.

I'm trying this with .htaccess but can't get it to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/application/files"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is amiss here. The server will respond very quickly that the files don't exist. It cannot be taking the server 25 seconds to respond with a 404.

That said, in answer to your specific query, your rewrite rule simply rewrites to the exact same thing. I think what you mean to have is a 404 returned for anything in "/application/files". So that would be achieved as so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/application/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

But it's only going to make a difference of micro-seconds. Your problem must be something else, either mis-reading the report or some other problem.

**Update**

Added check for existence of file before returning 404 (see comments).

And I see what you're saying the problem is, your web app code is causing the delay, so really you should fix your web-app or just stop it from being responsible for serving the resources and let the server handle it. This duplication of what the server core is built to do is not ideal.

Comment: Hmm .. it worked but it also blocks css and js assets. Is there any way to block only images?

Comment: I updated it so that it checks if the file exists, how's that?

Comment: Well of course, what else do you expect to be returned, other than a 404, for something that doesn't exist. That's what this code does. What is it you're wanting to do?

Comment: I just don't want them to take such long to process when I know they aren't there: http://imgur.com/a/1zWrw

Comment: What is it that's taking so long to process them? I don't know what that image means. The existing file at the top is taking twice as long. Nothing should be taking multiple seconds of those kinds of sizes. Is it benchmarking?

Comment: The first one is the main request, indeed its slow but maybe the application is preparing the files, but these image files are not required in the dev env so they aren't there. I was hoping to block them in a way that they don't take more than a few seconds to process.

Comment: Well that's what I'm saying, whatever is taking all this time to process them is not the server. You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Ah oh, thanks anyway, your htaccess config is definitely helpful though!

Comment: Thanks, best of luck tracking it down.